# Punctuation in salutation and closing in an email

Tags: writing, business-language

I usually use commas in salutation and closing phrase in emails like this below

> Dear XXX,
>
> Best regards,

I also see emails and letter of many people use commas. However,in an English for Work class, my teacher said that it should use colon like below for formal way.

> Dear XXX:
>
> Best regards (without punctuation)

I wonder if you share comments.

Comment: This isn't really an English language usage question so much as an opinion-based style query, but the way I was taught was to just write "Dear XXX" and "Best/Kind/Whatever regards" with no additional punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

Colon or comma is acceptable in the salutation, and one or the other should always be used. However, the colon is considered more formal.

The closing phrase should always end in a comma.